# Laravel Querying Relationship Existence

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following query in my Laravel controller:

```php
public function getTeams(){      
  $teams = Team::whereHas('submissions', function($q){
    $q->limit(1);
  })->with(['submissions'])->get();

  return response()->json(['data'=>$teams]);
}
```

Team model:

```php
   public function submissions(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\submission', 'team_id', 'id');
    }
```

Submission model:

```php
public function team(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'id', 'team_id');
}
```

Now I am trying to get only one submission in **getTeams** method. But the limit function isn't working correctly. It doesn't return any errors. It returns all submissions for each team. I only want 1 submission. How do I make it work?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $teams = Team::whereHas('submissions')
    ->with([
        'submissions' => function($query) {
            $query->limit(1);
        }
    ])->get();
```

Comment: @WahyuKristianto what do you mean?

Comment: @user8501960 My answer help you??

Comment: @Davit not really what I wanted. With your code it only returned 1 team only. But I got what I wanted after I looked at your code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to limit eager loading.

You can use a `HasOne` relationship:

```php
public function submission() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\submission', 'team_id', 'id');
}

$teams = Team::has('submission')->with('submission')->get();
```

This will still fetch all submissions in the background, but only show one for each `$team`.

BTW: You could improve the query by removing `has('submission')` and filtering the teams afterwards.

```php
$teams = Team::with('submission')->get();
$teams = $teams->where('submission', '!==', null)
```